# C# How to access each other form objects

Tags: c#, winforms

Below this code I'm trying to figure out how these forms can freely accessed their both objects. In these code,

- ITEMCount can access the objects of SIMSProduct
- On the other side although SIMSProduct can see the objects of ITEMCount
  (There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'view' of 'SIMSProduct.SIMSProduct(ITEMCount)')

.

```
//Form that use SIMSPRODUCT controls
public partial class ITEMCount : Form
{
    SIMSProduct  _view;
    public  ITEMCount(SIMSProduct view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _view = view;
        DisplayQuantity();
    }
}


// Form controls that been accessed by ITEMCOUNT
public partial class SIMSProduct : UserControl
{
    ITEMCount _view;
    public SIMSProduct(ITEMCount view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _view = view;
    }          

    private void btn_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (searchclicked = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_code.Text))
        {
            CustomNotifcation.Show("Please select your item", CustomNotifcation.AlertType.warning);
        }
        else
        {
            if (searchclicked = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_name.Text))
            {
                CustomNotifcation.Show("Please select your item", CustomNotifcation.AlertType.warning);
            }
            else
            {
                new ITEMCount(this).ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Code for calling the SIMSProduct form
public partial class SIMSMain : UserControl
{
    public SIMSMain()
    {    
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_products_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new SIMSProduct(); // this where error point out
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel3.Controls.Clear();
        panel3.Controls.Add(obj); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even run since `SIMSProduct` requires `ITEMCount` as parameter

Comment: Hmmm.. Can you give me a right way in doing these. An example of.. Accessing each other objects

Comment: I will in minute but it is not solution to this problem

Comment: Sometimes a good suggestion/example would be able to help me to solved this on my own. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does accessing flow works:

```
public partial class MyFirstForm : Form
{
    private string SomeString = "Some private variable";
    public string PublicString = "Some public variable";

    public MyFirstForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(Form2 f = new Form2(this))
        {
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    private MyFirstForm form;

    public Form2(MyFirstForm form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if(form == null)
            throw new Exception("Form you passed is not assigned!");

        this.form = form;
        form.SomeString = "I just changed string in first form";
    }
}
```

In comment you asked me `what if i create this in form 2 : private string SomeoneString = "Some private variable"; How can i access this in form 1 ?` - Answer is you cannot - cannot on easy way and that is because `private` variables are not accessible directly from other classes. There are 3 solutions. First is to make that variable public and use it like this:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    TestForm2 tf2; //Create global Variable for Second form which will be accessible from whole First Form Class

    public string StringInFirstForm = "Blank"; //Need to be public

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tf2 = new TestForm2(this); //Assign new object(form) to globally created variable(Second form)
        tf2.Show(); //Important to use Show not ShowDialog since if you use ShowDialog it will stop further code from executing
    }
}

public partial class TestForm2 : Form
{
    TestForm tf;

    public TestForm2(TestForm tf)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tf = tf;

        tf.StringInFirstForm = "I have changed string";
    }
}
```

Second way of accessing private variable is using property:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    TestForm2 tf2; //Create global Variable for Second form which will be accessible from whole First Form Class

    public string StringProperty
    {
        //Since there is no get{ } user can only SET property and when he does that property gets passed value and put that value into private variable in this class
        set
        { 
            StringInFirstForm = value;
            MessageBox.Show("You have changed value of StringInFristForm using property named StringProperty");
        }
    }
    private string StringInFirstForm = "Blank";

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tf2 = new TestForm2(this); //Assign new object(form) to globally created variable(Second form)
        tf2.Show(); //Important to use Show not ShowDialog since if you use ShowDialog it will stop further code from executing
    }
}

public partial class TestForm2 : Form
{
    TestForm tf;

    public TestForm2(TestForm tf)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tf = tf;

        tf.StringProperty = "I have changed string";

        string Test = tf.StringProperty; // This will return error which will say that property could only be set but not get
    }
}
```

Third option for setting private value in class is through public method.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    TestForm2 tf2;

    private string StringInFirstForm = "Blank";

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tf2 = new TestForm2(this);
        tf2.Show();
    }

    public void ChangeVariable(string Whatever)
    {
        StringInFirstForm = Whatever;
        MessageBox.Show("You have changed StringInFirstForm value using method ChangeVariable");
    }
}

public partial class TestForm2 : Form
{
    TestForm tf;

    public TestForm2(TestForm tf)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tf = tf;

        tf.ChangeVariable("Some String");
    }
}
```

There are few possibilities of accessing variables. Hope it helps :)

Comment: what if i create this in form 2 : private string SomeoneString = "Some private variable"; How can i access this in form 1 ?

Comment: @Anonymous Look at edited. I have given everything from myself to explain more than needed so you know it for future :)